# How to write recursive function properly?

Tags: python

Im new to Python and therefore apologize if the question ist to basic:

I would like to write a function which calculates the minimum monthly payment needed in order pay off a credit card balance within 12 months using recursion.

Given the following:

```
initialBalance = 1000 # Thats my initial balance on card / debt
annualInterest = .2
startPeriod = 1 # when I start to begin my pament
minMonthPayment = 5 # I begin a monthly payment of 5 $

def repayment(initialBalance,annualInterest,minMonthPayment,startPeriod):

    while startPeriod < 12 and initialBalance > 0:
        monthRate = annualInterest/12
        interest = monthRate * initialBalance
        initialBalance -= minMonthPayment
        initialBalance += interest
        startPeriod += 1
        # Here I check if I still havent paid off the balance with initial 5 dollars
        # If not then I would like to call the function again and increase the minMonthPayment 
    if initialBalance > 0:
        repayment(initialBalance,
                  annualInterest,
                  minMonthPayment + 5,
                  startPeriod)
    return round(initialBalance,1)

print(repayment(1000,.2,5,1))
```

However that doesnt seem to call the function appropriately and return:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

Comment: If  this is a *homework* exercise you should say so in your question.

Comment: That error means that you've called the function more times than your computer can handle. Often that happens because you create an infinite loop, so the function never returns a value. Throw in some print statements and see if you can figure out why it's never returning.

Comment: A good practice when writing a recursive procedure/function is to identify the terminal condition and write it first - ensuring that your process will stop at some point.

Comment: Hello @wwii, thats not a homework exercise. Therefore I did not mention it in my question. Im far to old to make homework. That is however a question I found on the MIT Homepage. There is also a solution which doesnt use recursion. Therefore my question is pretty plain as possible

Comment: Recursion can be a tricky topic. What I recommend you do is get a paper and pen, and execute the program yourself. Go through, and write down the value of each variable on each recursive call. Somewhere down the line, you'll find _why_ your terminal condition is continually failing, and(hopefully)be able to remedy the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When coding recursive functions you have to first answer the question when does this function stop going deeper and actually return a value. This check will usually be the first few lines of your recursive function.

So first you should check if the function should stop, and if it doesn't need to stop, that is, if it should go deeper you have to change the parameters you pass down to make sure it eventually satisfies this condition.

For example a simple recursive function to print all elements of a list would look like this:

```
def print_list_recursive(list):
    # This is the condition that answers the question 'do we need to go deeper?'
    if list is empty: # DON'T GO DEEPER
        return
    else: # We have to go deeper
        first_element = remove_first_element(list)
        print first_element
        print_list_recursive(list) # list parameter is changed
```

Note how the parameter `list` changes every time we go deeper. Each time one element is removed so eventually the list will be empty and we will return (stop going deeper).

Recursion will seem really easy once you define your problem recursively and define the stopping condition.

In the "print list" problem you should see that to print a list you can just print the first element and then call print_list on the rest of the list, which again prints the first element and then calls print_list on the rest of the list... So when do we stop? When we get to the stopping condition, that is, when the list is empty.

This same logic you can apply when coding any recursive function.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You're not resetting your startPeriod variable.

The first time the function is executed this is what the state looks like

```
def repayment(initialBalance,annualInterest,minMonthPayment,startPeriod):

    while startPeriod < 12 and initialBalance > 0:
        monthRate = annualInterest/12
        interest = monthRate * initialBalance
        initialBalance -= monthlyPayment
        initialBalance += interest
        startPeriod += 1

    #1st call of repayment: startPeriod is now 12 and initialBalance is 
    #greater than 0

    if initialBalance > 0:
        repayment(initialBalance,
                  annualInterest,
                  minMonthPayment,
                  startPeriod + 5) #start period becomes 17 here
    return round(initialBalance,1)
```

The second time the function is executed this is what the state looks like

```
def repayment(initialBalance,annualInterest,minMonthPayment,startPeriod):

    #2nd call of repayment: startPeriod is now 17 so this loop is never 
    #run and your initialBalance will not be decreased
    while startPeriod < 12 and initialBalance > 0:
        monthRate = annualInterest/12
        interest = monthRate * initialBalance
        initialBalance -= monthlyPayment
        initialBalance += interest
        startPeriod += 1

    #initialBalance is still greater than zero in the 2nd call of 
    #repayment since the while loop wasn't run. You have created an 
    #infinataly recursive function
    if initialBalance > 0:
        repayment(initialBalance,
                  annualInterest,
                  minMonthPayment,
                  startPeriod + 5)
    return round(initialBalance,1)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I just realized I did a mistake after you reminded me of the start. Actually I call `print(repayment(1000,.2,5,1)) `, where the start period starts with 1 and i increment minpayment by 5. I updated the question. Sorry!!

Comment: Besides that I see what you mean with not initializing the start :). I suppose the recursion fails because there is no start defined except when calling the function initialy

Answer (score -1):

I am not familiar with Python much, but here I did what you asked in Java, maybe you can compare and apply it to Python ( I will try to make one on an online python compiler)

```
import java.lang.Math; // headers MUST be above the first class

public class PaymentCalculator
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{

System.out.print(repayment(1000,2,25,1));
}

static int repayment(int initialBalance, int annualInterest, int minMonthPayment, int startPeriod){

int monthRate = annualInterest / 12;
int interest = monthRate * initialBalance;


  for(int i =0; i < 12; i++){
    initialBalance -= minMonthPayment;
    initialBalance += interest;
    startPeriod++;

  }

if(initialBalance == 0 || initialBalance < 0){
  return minMonthPayment;
}
else
{
 return repayment(1000,2,minMonthPayment+25,1);
}        


}
}
```

Comment: I hope this would be helpful for you